# ReflectionException error class admin does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating an Admin backend for my laravel project. It is using the laravel Auth scaffolding. I am now getting this error after coming back to it after the weekend and I am struggling to find an error. I have checked all spellings and capitalization. I have ran composer update etc etc but still no luck. Here is the error below, I do have the admin class and its in the `namespace App`, not sure whats going on:

```
ReflectionException error class admin does not exist.
```

Web.php file

```
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
  Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
  Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
  Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
});
```

AdminLoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('admin')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        //Validate the form data
        $this->validate($request, [
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        // Attempt to log the user in
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
          // If successful, then redirect to tehir inteded page
          return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }

        // unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: well, this is the error, now where is the code?

Comment: Maybe its in my web.php file here is  the code for that Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
  Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
  Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
  Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
});

Comment: please update your post with [the related code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have fixed it!! In the AdminLoginController, I added this `'guest:admin'` to this instead of just `'admin'` betweeen the middleware parenthese :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }
```